# how to import the gda-ui module in python?

Tags: python, python-module, gobject-introspection

I'm trying to get started with libgda in python (3.4). To import the Gda module i do `from gi.repository import Gda`

I want to use `GdauiTreeStore` but i don't know how to import the Gda-ui module...

Things like that didn't work:

- `from gi.repository import Gdaui`
- `from gi.repository import GdaUi`
- `from gi.repository import GdaUI`
- `from gi.repository import Gda-ui`
- `from gi.repository import Gda-Ui`
- `from gi.repository import Gda-UI` (and same with underscore instead of dash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure `libgda-ui` (and its development package) are installed? Ever since introspection was [added to libgda-ui in 2010](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libgda/commit/libgda-ui/Makefile.am?id=c43a60bab708ffcca0a4fc96d6c080fd49365f17), the GIR file has been called `Gdaui-$version.gir`.

Importing it using:

```
from gi.repository import Gdaui
```

works fine for me in Python 2 and 3.

Note that if the GIR file *did* contain a hyphen in its name, you might be able to import it using:

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module('gi.repository.Gda-ui')
```

though I have been unable to test this.